# how to extend React.SFC type in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In react typings we find the following:

```
type SFC<P = {}> = StatelessComponent<P>;
interface StatelessComponent<P = {}> {
    (props: P & { children?: ReactNode }, context?: any): ReactElement<any> | null;
    propTypes?: ValidationMap<P>;
    contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;
    defaultProps?: Partial<P>;
    displayName?: string;
}
```

I want to extend it with a property `fragment`. I've created `index.d.ts` in my `typings/react` folder, but can't figure out how to extend the type properly, so it wouldn't break the rest of the code. I've tried something like:

```
declare module "react" {
  import React, { SFC as ReactSFC} from "react";

  export type SFC<P = {}> = ReactSFC<P> & { fragment: any };

  export = React;
}
```

but it breaks JSX code basically

Is there a proper way of doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to overwrite a type alias like that.  Instead, declare your own `StatelessComponent` interface under the same module name, and it will merge with the original interface.  Here is the proper syntax:

```
declare module "dummy" {
  module "react" {
    interface StatelessComponent<P = {}> {
      fragment?: any;
    }
  }
}
```

The outer module declaration is needed to make the inner module declaration an "augmentation" instead of shadowing the original module, as mentioned in [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17736#issuecomment-338785578).  That trick is unfortunately not properly documented AFAIK.

Comment: yes, sorry it was `?` originally in my code, but I deleted it out of frustration :-) The problem is, that in the example above any `React.SFC` component becomes of type `any` - loses `defaultProps` for example. Not that big of a deal, but something is conceptually wrong here.. I also tried regular `declare namespace React` but it doesn't help either

Comment: all the other imported components from other lib kind of lose their properties

Comment: See the revised answer.

Comment: Quite nicely explained

Comment: wow, I could have never imagined this type of concoction! Thanks, will give a try now